# "strict" mode for QML?

Tags: qt, qml, assert

Does Qt's QML language provide any kind of "strict" mode? In particular, there are two features I'd like:

- Application crash on reference to `undefined` or `null` (e.g. `foo = bar` when `foo` is an existing property but `bar` is not defined, and `foo.bar` when `foo` is null)
- "hard" asserts (the `console.assert` feature does not crash the application).

Comment: You **want** crashes?

Comment: @ddriver Yes, during development. Much easier than trying to read the console output and guess how serious various problems are. (This is an app that in my opinion is not terribly well designed, at least on the QML side of things.)

Comment: @ddriver For a more general defense of crashing applications, and for an article about error handling that I happen to love and enjoy promoting, see the section "Bugs Aren't Recoverable Errors!" here: http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/

Comment: I had no idea it is so hard to read the console output... or that it is better to crash than to get a message what and where went wrong.

Comment: @ddriver The console output (in this case) is noisy with things that don't matter. And the crash should *include* a message about what went wrong; it's not an either/or.

Comment: Depends on your workflow. I don't get any noise in the console, only warnings when something goes wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108660/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-ddriver).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. Use qml lint**

Run qmllint on all .qml and .js files in your build setup

```
find ./myproject -type f -regex ".*\.\(qml\|js\)" -exec "$QT_DIR/bin/qmllint" \{\} +
```

**2. Crash app on QML error/warning**

Write a custom QDebug message handler function `static void handler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext& context, const QString &message);` you register via `qInstallMessageHandler(&MyQDebugMessageHandler::handler);` that turns QML warnings into fatal logs:

```
if (type == QtWarningMsg)
{
    auto fatalWarnings = std::vector<QString>{
            QStringLiteral("ReferenceError:"),
            QStringLiteral("is not a type"),
            QStringLiteral("File not found"),
    };

    for (const auto &s : fatalWarnings)
    {
        if (message.contains(s))
        {
            type = QtFatalMsg;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then make sure that QDebug messages of type `QtFatalMsg` crash the app.

**3. Crash on console.assert()**

`console.assert()` creates errors but nothing specific to detect them. So adapt point 2. to crash the app on errors as well.

Comment: My gosh. How did I not know about qmllint? I've wanted something like that ever since I began working on this GUI. Thank you so much for that and the rest.